# Remove prefix and suffix from a URL copied to input field

Tags: javascript, html

I'm totally new in the world of coding, so I got lost in a tiny project I created for myself to practice.
I would like to create a very simple web page where there would be an input field.

1. To the imput field I want to copy a URL

https://kalamajka.aa1.anythig.com/ert/eer/ui/eerr/dda1d

2. There should be a function to remove https:// and /ert/eer/ui/eerr/dda1d

In Excel, I created this function which is searching for the first 3 '/' and getting the substring'kalamajka.aa1.anythig.com':

```
=IFERROR(MID(B2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",CHAR(1),2))+1, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",CHAR(1),3)) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B2,"/",CHAR(1),2))-1),"Please copy the full url")
```

Though, I could not find the equivalent for HTML function I could use instead.

3. It should be copiable, so I found the following function.
   }

I have issues adding the result of a function to a function. So, I would like to add result of the substring function (where there's no https and other unnecessary suffixes in the URL) to the clipboard.

4. And this is the hardest part: an if-else statement. So, if URL contains **aa1**, then it should add suffix: /elment/path. Else, add the suffix 'path/toelement':

If statement 1: https://kalamajka.aa1.anythig.com/elment/path
If statemenet 2: https://kalamajka.bb1.anythig.com/path/toelement

It looks like in the following way so far:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    div { border: 1px solid red; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
    #SACURL { background-color: white; }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
    <p> Copy the FULL URL </p>
    <input id="URL"></input>
    <button onclick="GenerateURL()"> Remove prefix and suffix (https) and others </button>
    <hr>        
        <p> Substring URL </p>
        <div>
            <div id="SubstringURL">
            <hr>
                
            URL with no https and suffix should appear here.
        
                </div>
                    <hr>
                        <button onclick="CopyURL()"> Copied </button>
                </div>
      <div>
            <div>
            If statement (if URL contains aa1), then it should add suffix: elment/path
            </div>
            <button onclick="OpenURLonNewPage"> Open URL on a new tab </button>
        </div>
        
    
    </div>
    
    
    
</body>

<script>
function GenerateURL() {
    var valt1 = document.getElementById("URL").value;
    <!-- alert(valt1); -->
    document.getElementById("SubstringURL").innerHTML = valt1;

}
function CopyURL() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    div { border: 1px solid red; padding:10px; margin:10px; }
    
</style>
<body>
    <div>
    <p> Copy the FULL URL </p>
    <input id="URL"></input>
    <button onclick="GenerateURL()"> Remove prefix and suffix (https) and others </button>
    <hr>        
        <p> Substring URL </p>
        <div>
            <div id="SubstringURL">
            <hr>
                
            URL with no https and suffix should appear here.
        
                </div>
                    <hr>
                        <button onclick="CopyURL()"> Copied </button>
                </div>
      <div>
            <div>
            If statement (if URL contains aa1), then it should add suffix: elment/path
            </div>
            <button onclick="OpenURLonNewPage"> Open URL on a new tab </button>
        </div>
        
    
    </div>
    
    
    
</body>

<script>
function GenerateURL() {
    var valt1 = document.getElementById("URL").value;
    <!-- alert(valt1); -->
    document.getElementById("SubstringURL").innerHTML = valt1;

}
function CopyURL() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = document.getElementById("GenerateSACURL").value;

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
  
  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
  
  function OpenURLonNewPage()  IF STATEMENT FOR PREFIX AND SUFFIX{
    

}



</script>
```

Could you please help me understand the logic? I seem to fail every time with it. Also it's not clear how a function's result can be used in another function. How can I reference that?

I would be really grateful for your help! :)

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: You have multiple body tags. You should only have one. Your script tag(s) should go inside the one body tag (or head tag)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the website endpoint using the below code

```
var myurl = "https://kalamajka.aa1.anythig.com/ert/eer/ui/eerr/dda1d"
myurl.split('/')[2];
```

result 'kalamajka.aa1.anythig.com'

you can try running the code in chrome console

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is in your HTML. Your function says OpenURLonNewPage without the required ().

Yours: `<button onclick="OpenURLonNewPage">`

What It Should Be: `<button onclick="OpenURLonNewPage()">`

Below is a script that would work for this. I intentionally broke this out so it is easier to understand since you are a beginner.

The GenerateURL function removes the "https://" from the URL and generates a new URL based of your If/Else requirements.

The CopyURL function then strips off the end of the URL to provide you with a copied URL without the path at the end after .com.

The OpenURLonNewPage function takes your generated URL from the GenerateURL function and opens it in a new tab. Note: "http://" had to be added in order for the browser to know you want to open a website. Otherwise, it would attempt to open a local file.

```
<script>
        function GenerateURL() {
            var valt1 = document.getElementById("URL").value;
            valt1 = valt1.replace('https://', '');
            if (valt1.indexOf("aa1")>= 0) {
                valt1 = valt1.split('/')[0];
                valt1 = valt1 + "/element/path"
            }
           else {
                valt1 = valt1.split('/')[0];
                valt1 = valt1 + "/path/toelement"
            }
            console.log("Stripped URL: " + valt1)
            return valt1;
        }

        function CopyURL(valt1) {
            var copy = GenerateURL(valt1);
            copy = copy.split("/")[0];
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(copy);
            console.log("Copied Url: " + copy)
        }
        
        function OpenURLonNewPage(valt1) {
           var newUrl = GenerateURL(valt1);
            window.open('http://' + newUrl, '_blank')
        }

        
        </script>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for! :)

Comment: Hi Ben,

Thank you so much for checking this issue. I was trying to use your code, though it didn't work out, so I started experimenting.

I tried to use the following functions, but I cannot get any results in the second function after referencing the var created in the first function. I'll add my next comment the code.


Do you have any idea why I cannot seem to add a var result created in the first function to the second function to be used?

Comment: function GenerateURL() {
            var valt1 = document.getElementById("URL").value;
            var removehttps = valt1.replace('https://', '');
 
            document.getElementById("SubstringURL").innerHTML = removehttps;
            window.removehttps= CopyURL.getSource().getBindingContext();
            } 
function CopyURL() {
    var copy=window.removehttps;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copy).then(() => {
       
        alert("Copied to clipboard");
    });
  }